# How to make plugins/libraries with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

I have a good experience of HTML, JS, CSS and jQuery. Now I am looking forward to create my own libraries or plugins. I have seen many of them but couldn't get where to start from and what to do to start it. I am looking forward to stackoverflow so that I can get opinions from pros. Can you please tell me what do I need to know and what code is used for creating plugins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can find a jQuery course of creating your own plugin => [How to Create a Basic Plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Answer (score 3):

to create simple plugin you only need to put

```
$.fn.pluginName = function() {
   // this here is elements selected by selector
   return this; // don't forget return this, so your plugin will be chainable
};
```

and you will be able to call it from selector like built in functions/methods

```
$('div.foo').pluginName();
```

if you know html/js/css and jquery you already know everything you need to know, the only thing that you need is idea for a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**[How to Create a Jquery Plugin](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/10/how-to-create-jquery-plugin.html)**

Comment: can you just please explain it?